# How to take content of google captcha image with PHP

Tags: php, curl, recaptcha

when I use php Curl to search on google, sometimes ask me image captcha. I need to get this image content as file64 format.

The response url:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html dir="LTR"> 
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
  <title>https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=Ak%C4%B1n+Evrenkaya&amp;sourceid=navclient&amp;gbv=1&amp;num=100&amp;pws=0&amp;nfpr=1</title>
 </head> 
 <body style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; color: #000; padding:20px; font-size:18px;" onload="e=document.getElementById('captcha');if(e){e.focus();} if(solveSimpleChallenge) {solveSimpleChallenge(,);}"> 
  <div style="max-width:400px;"> 
   <hr noshade size="1" style="color:#ccc; background-color:#ccc;">
   <form id="captcha-form" action="index" method="post">
     Devam etmek için lütfen aşağıdaki karakterleri yazın:
    <img src="/sorry/image?id=11494140825610243265&amp;q=EgQtiGrOGI-Pl5UGIhCXtJAH1U88k7g0k0PryvgtMgJjbg&amp;hl=tr&amp;continue=https://www.google.com.tr/search%3Fq%3DAk%25C4%25B1n%2BEvrenkaya%26sourceid%3Dnavclient%26gbv%3D1%26num%3D100%26pws%3D0%26nfpr%3D1" border="1" alt="Lütfen resimleri etkinleştirin">
    <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" id="captcha" size="12" style="font-size:16px; padding:3px 0 3px 5px; margin-left:0px;"> 
    <input type="submit" name="btn-submit" value="Gönder" style="font-size:18px; padding:4px 0;"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="EgQtiGrOGI-Pl5UGIhCXtJAH1U88k7g0k0PryvgtMgJjbg">
    <input type="hidden" name="continue" value="https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=Ak%C4%B1n+Evrenkaya&amp;sourceid=navclient&amp;gbv=1&amp;num=100&amp;pws=0&amp;nfpr=1"> 
   </form> 
   <hr noshade size="1" style="color:#ccc; background-color:#ccc;"> 
   <div style="font-size:13px;"> <b>Bu sayfa hakkında</b>Bu neden oldu? 
    <div id="infoDiv" style="display:none; background-color:#eee; padding:10px; margin:0 0 15px 0; line-height:1.4em;">
      Bu sayfa, Google'ın, bilgisayar ağınızdan gelen ve <a href="//www.google.com/policies/terms/">Hizmet Şartları</a>'nı ihlal ettiği görülen istekleri otomatik olarak algılaması durumunda görüntülenir. Bu istekler kesildikten kısa bir süre sonra engelleme sona erer. Bu arada, yukarıdaki CAPTCHA sorusunu yanıtlayarak hizmetlerimizi kullanmaya devam edebilirsiniz.Bu trafik, otomatik istekler gönderen kötü niyetli bir yazılım, tarayıcı eklentisi veya komut dosyası tarafından gönderilmiş olabilir. Ağ bağlantınızı paylaşıyorsanız, yöneticinizden yardım isteyin; aynı IP adresini kullanan başka bir bilgisayar bu soruna yol açmış olabilir. <a href="//support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640">Daha fazla bilgi edinin</a>Bazen robotların kullandığı bilinen ileri düzey terimler kullanır veya istekleri çok hızlı gönderirseniz CAPTCHA sorusunu yanıtlamanız istenebilir. 
    </div> IP adresi: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxSaat: 2022-06-12T11:01:37ZURL: https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=Ak%C4%B1n+Evrenkaya&amp;sourceid=navclient&amp;gbv=1&amp;num=100&amp;pws=0&amp;nfpr=1 
   </div>
  </div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since the whole point of captchas is to stop you automating the search, I imagine Google have made this as difficult as possible.

Comment: Yeah, actually this was working till last week, but google announced a new update which if you solve a recapthca v2 then shows another image capthca like above. The most appropriate solution for me is solving again image capthca.